# Vitest and unimport with axios, pusher and/or Echo on window object

Tags: vuejs3, vite, jsdom, laravel-echo, vitest

I'm using `vitest` and `@vue/test-utils` to test a Laravel/Vue3 UI. The `boostrap.js` file adds `axios`, `pusher` and `Echo` to the window object and the components then have access to use them directly without importing:

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo(...);
```

Here is my vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import Unimport from 'unimport/unplugin';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: [
        'resources/sass/app.scss',
        'resources/js/app.js',
      ],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: null,
          includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      },
    }),
    Unimport.vite({
      addons: {
        vueTemplate: true,
      },
      presets: [
        'vue',
        'vue-router',
        'pinia',
      ],
      imports: [
        { name: 'default', as: 'messages', from: '../../../utils/messages.js' }
      ]
    })
  ],
  test: {
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      reporter: ['text', 'lcovonly', 'html'],
    },
    environment: 'happy-dom',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
});
```

How/where can I update this so that if I mock axios, pusher and/or Echo, I can then write tests without hitting errors like `ReferenceError: Echo is not defined` or `ReferenceError: axios is not defined`? Here is an example where I am mocking Echo successfully:

```
vi.mock('laravel-echo', async () => {
  const actual = vi.importActual('laravel-echo');

  return {
    ...actual,
    default: {
      private: vi.fn(() => {
        return {
          listenToAll: vi.fn(),
        };
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

but getting the `ReferenceError: Echo is not defined` error when the component interacts with Echo without importing it. Adding `import Echo from 'laravel-echo';` removes the error, but I would like to have my tests match by UI environment so that I do not need to add imports for things that are accessible to the components.

Also, while importing removes the error during testing, it then starts throwing the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Echo.private is not a function at...` in the actual browser.

Tldr; how can I emulate the bootsrapping that happens in `bootstrap.js` so that I can mock and interact with any dependencies that have been added to the window object such as axios, pusher, lodash, Echo...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Chrome 71+, Firefox 65+, and Safari 12.1+, and Node.js 12+, check if you can mock and attach the necessary dependencies to the `globalThis` object.
See "[What is globalThis, and why should you start using it?](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-is-globalthis-why-use-it/)" from [Faraz Kelhini,](https://eloux.com/#ci_about_widget-3), Dec. 2019.

Create a new file `tests/bootstrap.js`, and within this file, add the necessary dependencies to the `globalThis` object:

```js
// tests/bootstrap.js

import axios from 'axios';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

globalThis.axios = axios;
globalThis.Pusher = Pusher;

// Mock the Echo instance with a jest mock function
// Adjust the mock implementation as necessary for your tests
globalThis.Echo = {
  private: jest.fn(() => ({
    listenToAll: jest.fn(),
  })),
};

// Configure axios as in bootstrap.js
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';
```

Next, update your [Vite configuration](https://vitejs.dev/config/) to include this bootstrap file in your testing setup. Adjust the `vite.config.js` file to reference your `tests/bootstrap.js` file in the `test` configuration:

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  test: {
    // ...
    runner: {
      runner: "jest",
    },
    setupFiles: [
      './tests/bootstrap.js',  // Adjust the path as necessary
    ],
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Finally, in your Vitest mocking setup, since you are using [`vi.mock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock) to mock your `laravel-echo`, make sure to return the actual global `Echo` instance (which is now your mocked version), rather than mocking a new one:

```js
vi.mock('laravel-echo', async () => {
  return globalThis.Echo;
});
```

With this setup, your global dependencies should be mocked and available in your test files, just as they are in your application files.